# SSM Agent Ping Status 'Connected' even when Raspberry pi is unplugged

Tags: amazon-web-services, raspberry-pi, aws-ssm

I installed the ssm agent on my Pi Zero W (running Pi OS Lite). The device appears in the Fleet Manager/Managed instances. However, when I unplug it, it continues to show as connected for a good 5-10 minutes.

Is this indicative of some sort of problem with my config?

Is there any way I can change this frequency/make it realtime?

Comment: This is normal. EC2 also has this Behaviour.

Comment: Jellycsc - If this is normal, What is my realtime option, Cloudwatch?